# Html 5 video tag and codecs problem

Tags: html5-video

I have a mkv file. It's video codec is avc and audio codec is ac3.

How can i put it into a html5 video tag?

I use the

```
<source src="01.mkv" type="video/x-matroska" codecs="a_ac3, avc">
```

but in safari 5 or chorome4 it doesn't works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `<source>` tag is malformed.  You need to put the codec information inside the value of the `type` attribute instead, eg:

```
<source src="01.mkv" type='video/x-matroska; codecs="a_ac3, avc"'>
```

The `type` attribute contains a full MIME specification, and `codecs` is an optional parameter for some MIME types. There is no separate `codecs` attribute on the `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

`<source` is not the top level HTML5 video tag, which is named `<video>`. You can find out more [from this tutorial.](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) Are you using `<source>` inside of `<video>`?