# No sound while playing MKV with HTML5

Tags: html, audio, video, html5-video

I'm trying to play a .MKV file with HTML5. Video works fine but there is no sound, I can't unmute the video.

```
<video src="video.mkv" type='video/x-matroska' codecs='theora, vorbis'></video>
```

I'm using Chrome 24.

Comment: Have you added the mkv mime type?

Comment: MKV is just a container, it can contain any type(s) of audio and video streams.  What type of audio stream is in the file.

Comment: Yes I have added the mkv mime type into a .htaccess file.
The audio type is AC-3 and video type is AVC.

But even with <video controls="controls"><source src='video.mkv' type='video/x-matroska' codecs='avc, a_ac3'></video> it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html 5 video tag and codecs problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035295/html-5-video-tag-and-codecs-problem)

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the audio codec that was used. Chrome probably doesn't support it. No, I don't know how to fix it other than to find out what audio codec it's using and either change it or get a browser extension that will support it. I will engage you to convert the video into different format like MP4/OGG.

```
<video width="500px" controls>
  <source src="yourvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="yourvideo.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Your can VLC web plugin. It takes some few steps to configure and get it to work.

Read more about https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin#Input_object

```
<embed id="divxplayer" type="video/divx" width="1024" height="768" 
src ="path_to_file" autoPlay=\"true\" 
pluginspage=\"http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/\"></embed>
```

Other question related to this : [How to playback MKV video in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192713/how-to-playback-mkv-video-in-web-browser)

Answer (score 1):

you should convert it to these formate MP4,WebM or Ogg.
My opinion, MP4 is the best because it is compressed (low size/ fast loading).
Try conversion program like "xilisoft video conveter" or any online audio converter.
here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="yourfile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="yourfile.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
    
</body> 
</html>
```