# Include video in HTML

Tags: html, video, local

I want to include a video for my website which is locally available in my C drive. But after I have done the website only plays audio. If I add a thumbnail only that image is shown. My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset ="UTF-8">
      <meta name ="description" content="It is nice website">
      <title>Ajay Web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <video src="C:\Users\ajayr\Downloads\[TIF]_S04_E16_The_Big_Bang_Theory_720p_10bit.mkv"  controls></video>
      
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are three supported video formats: MP4, WebM, and Ogg.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Answer (score 0):

MKV is - e. g. - in Chrome not supported without plugins or extensions.

Having a look here on SO, I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192713/how-to-playback-mkv-video-in-web-browser) about this (incl. solution).

Comment: The answer for that question is somewhat unclear. But all they trying to say is you cant play a MKV file in chrome right ,? I am just learning HTML.

Comment: @Ajayx no problem about learning something new. pls follow the link and check the attribute at the video tag - seems like a hack/workaround.

Comment: @Ajay you need to provide a relative url